# missing android files in eclipse

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I'm really new to android and I got an issue that I don't clearly understand.

A few hours ago I worked on a project, saved all files and closed eclipse. When I restarted it a few minutes ago, several files are missing, namely the AndroidManifest (saw some other questions around here on SO), but also all XML-files I created and saved in `res/layout`, `res/values` and `res/menu` (Their not only missing in eclipse, but also when I open the project via explorer). On the other hand, in my main Activity, eclipse doesn't show any error at calling of `setContentView(R.layout.show_start_site)`.

I've read that most of the xml-files under res/ get compiled. But how can I process further on them after closing and reopening eclipse? Via explorer, under `classes/.../"appname"` I see the class files, e.g. `R$Layout.class`, `R$menu.class` and so on.

**UPDATE**

I just created a new workspace at a different (random) place, now everything works fine. Don't really understand why...

Comment: are those files still in that folder, if you view it from (window) file explorer?

Comment: no, only the class files, but no xml-files. The folder "menu", which I created manually, is there, but empty. But for example a .png-file imported in folder drawable is still visible both in folder an in eclipse

Comment: select the project and press F5... If it doesn't work, go to the project folder (explorer) and search for `AndroidManifest.xml`. If you didn't find it, you either deleted the file or I must say, your hard disk is damaged.

Comment: nothing worked. I'm 100% sure that I deleted nothing. I saw some issues on the internet, that it might have a coherency with the custom workspace target, but I cannot see that this might be the problem. But I also don't think that the problem is my harddisk, it is a) relatively new and b) never had any issues. I worked for over 4 months on a java project with no problems. A week ago, I reinstalled windows. Since then I got issues, but only with android projects (e.g. android manifest is always missing at other projects, the issue with the missing xml-files was now the first time I saw it)

Comment: On the other hand, in a second android project (where only the manifest is missing), all xml files are still existing.

Comment: Looks like your workspace has been changed, nothing else.

Comment: May be you are having the source and xml's in a different location than the android eclipse project (.metadata). Right click on the project > Resources > Location. See if you have created the files under these location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you change your workspace by any chance?

In Eclipse go to "File" and go down to switch workspace. It will show you what your current workspace is and make sure those files are in that workspace.